# How to fix some errors while setting up Visual Studio Code for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm setting up an IDE using Visual Studio Code for C++ and I have already downloaded and installed all the packages in MinGW Compiler and Git for using bash shell.

I followed this tutorial--> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_configure-debug-settings

However, there were several small details that differed in my case as i progressed through the tutorial for which I'm not aware of their impact(as I am a beginner):

1. c_cpp_properties.json was a little different in my case.

My code was this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

2. In tutorial under *configure debug settings*, it states: 'Note that the program name helloworld.exe matches what you specified in tasks.json'. On the contrary I had specified 'helloworld.cpp' instead of 'helloworld.exe' in tasks.json

Still I finished the tutorial, and while debugging as said in the tutorial, I got an error stating, helloworld.exe does not exist.

I'd be grateful if someone can provide some insights and ways to deal with these errors.

Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner while answering. Thank You.

Edit: The code for the file tasks.json that I'm using:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "helloworld",
                "helloworld.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The code for the file launch.json that I'm using:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm I did that because they had previously instructed to copy their code under "Create a build task" where they used 'helloworld.cpp'...so its self-contradictory.

Comment: The code should be `helloworld.cpp` the executable should be `helloworld.exe`.  `helloworld.cpp` should be mentioned in the build task. Note in the example the executable is `"helloworld",` I believe the `.exe` is assumed on MS Windows.

Comment: @drescherjm in reply to your first comment, I didn't use .cpp for the the instruction right after "-o". Instead i used it for the second one. I'll just attach the exact code I'm using for tasks.json and launch.json

Comment: I assume you did not get any building errors at all? Do you use aVast or some other AV with a sandbox feature? Did you look for the executable in explorer? You may want to disable the "hide extensions for known types" feature of the file explorer.

Comment: @drescherjm nope I guess I didn't receive any of those build errors and I don't use even use an antivirus atm let alone sandbox...windows defender's been doing pretty good...If anything seems odd, pardon me sir, I'm new in this area.

Comment: You may want to open a command window. change directory to the folder containing your project and type exactly the following: `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g -o helloworld helloworld.cpp` and see if that produces an error or do you get an executable in the folder.

Comment: @drescherjm it produces an error: g++.exe: error: helloworld.cpp: No such file or directory     g++.exe: fatal error: no input files

Comment: You need to do that in the folder containing `helloworld.cpp`. The error is saying it can't find `helloworld.cpp`. Type dir from the command line when you believe you are in the correct folder. Make sure that `helloworld.cpp` exists. And it is not named `helloworld.cpp.cpp`

Comment: @drescherjm oh ok...i did it again, this time in the right folder and it did produce an executable

Comment: Not sure why this is not working in Visual Studio Code. This is the exact command from your `tasks.json` file. Someone else will have to help with that.

Comment: @drescherjm alright..still, thanks for your precious time. Appreciate it a lot